# I'm trying to adjust my httpd.conf file on my server but can't find it

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, centos-6

I'm trying to make changes to the `httpd.conf` file on my server so I can have multiple websites on my Magento platform, however I am unable to find said `httpd.conf` file.

I'm using Centos 6 and Apache 2.4. I've tried using the search function in the c panel file manager and using shell to locate the file to no success. However I have to have one if I'm currently using an operational and function Magento site hosted on that server.

Is there any chance that it could be called something obscure?

Cheers.

Comment: If you're running on a shared host, you probably don't have access to the httpd.conf . . .

Answer (score 0):

One of these may shed some light on it - they print the locations of each VirtualHost entry in your configuration.

`sudo apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` or `sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` (one should work).

Last time I had to hunt for it on a cpanel server, Apache and configs were in `/usr/local/apache` or similar I think, and then included additional configurations from each cpanel account's home dir. That may have changed since then!

Comment: NB. 'apache2ctl' is just an alias / symlink to the main apache binary; called without arguments it executes `apache -t` to check a configuration.